# Web Bluetooth contribute new service/characteristic to own device

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

Web Bluetooth, from reading through the spec and the APIs, seems like it can only handle pairing with a BT device and then reading or writing to it.

But it doesn't seem to be able to expose a new service or a new characteristic on an existing service on the device in the machine the page utilizing Web Bluetooth runs on.

Is there a way I missed how Web Bluetooth can be used to create a new service for the duration of the page being open and allow other machines/devices to pair with the one running the script on the page and use this new service?

My main interest is mesh networking with BTLE using the Web Bluetooth API, but for that all devices running the page need to be able to not only connect to other peers, but also to be connectable-to by other peers. That part I have no idea how to achieve with the current API.

Can I get a definitive answer on whether it is possible to contribute new services to the BT device of the computer the script runs on? Links to this being discussed in the WGs and whatnot would also be great, I am interested in why it is not possible if that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have learnt a crucial piece of nomenclature which now allows me to answer this question: *peripheral mode*.

Not all Bluetooth adapters support it and the Web Bluetooth standard is not looking like it's going to support web pages acting as beacons/peripherals any time soon:

https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/issues/231

So, as of now, what I asked for is not possible.